# "random" and "random:" function for NSExpression's init(forFunction:arguments:)

Tags: cocoa, nsexpression

[Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:) says Function `random` returns

> An `NSNumber` object (a random integer value)

After running these two line of code:

```
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "random", arguments: [])
let value: AnyObject = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil)
```

What I get is a number between 0 and 1, such as 0.312047983519733.

---

As to Function `random:`, the document says it returns

> An `NSNumber` object (a random integer value between 0 and the value in the array (exclusive))

I try to use it as according to document (take a parameter which is an `NSArray` object containing one NSExpression object representing a number):

```
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "random:", arguments: [NSExpression(forConstantValue: 100)]) // The compiler says "Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT"
let value: AnyObject = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil)
```

The first line even cannot pass compiling. In the console, it says "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'random: is not a supported method.'**"

---

I'm not sure what the problem is. I've tried all functions for 
`init(forFunction:arguments:)`, all worked as described in the document except `random` and `random:`.

Comment: Looks like an Apple bug to me - when I try, it says "random: is not a supported method"

Comment: @MichaelL Me too, "random: is not a supported method" appears in the console. "Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT" appears just near that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because there is a slight difference in the selector name between `random` and `randomn:`. Notice the `n` at the end of the latter.

This should work

```
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "randomn:", arguments: 
[NSExpression(forConstantValue: 100)])
let value: AnyObject = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil)
```